# IF statement evaluating as "True" when condition criteria not met

Tags: excel, vba

Hi everyone.

I am trying to create a calculator that determines what action to take depending on the values of multiple gasses. Each gas will have a value within a cell that can fall within one of four ranges . Each gas is given a "priority rank" the range its value lies within. Then the highest priority determines what action to be taken.

The Problem:

The first If statement of each conditional block is being evaluated as "True" even if the value in the cell is greater than the value specified in the condition. How can I get the conditional statements to properly evaluate the condition based off the value in the cell.

Sub DGOA_Action_500kVA()

```
Dim HydrogenValue As Variant
Dim MethaneValue As Variant
Dim EthaneVaule As Variant
Dim EthyleneValue As Variant
Dim AcetyleneValue As Variant
Dim Action As Integer


Dim HydrogenPriority As Integer
Dim MethanePriority As Integer
Dim EthanePriority As Integer
Dim EthylenePriority As Integer
Dim AcetylenePriority As Integer

Worksheets("500 kVa").Activate
HydrogenValue = Worksheets("500 kVa").Range("B3").Select
MethaneValue = Worksheets("500 kVa").Range("C3").Select
EthaneVaule = Worksheets("500 kVa").Range("F3").Select
EthyleneValue = Worksheets("500 kVa").Range("G3").Select
AcetyleneValue = Worksheets("500 kVa").Range("H3").Select


Dim PriorityRange As Range
Set PriorityRange = Worksheets("500 kVa").Range("J3:P3")


If HydrogenValue < 2000 Then
    HydrogenPriority = 1
    MsgBox (Worksheets("500 kVa").Range("B6").Select)

    ElseIf HydrogenValue >= 2000 And HydrogenValue < 20000 Then
        HydrogenPriority = 2

    ElseIf HydrogenValue >= 20000 And HydrogenValue < 27000 Then
        HydrogenPriority = 3

    ElseIf HydrogenValue >= 27000 Then
        HydrogenPriority = 4
End If


If MethaneValue < 2000 Then
    MethanePriority = 1

    ElseIf MethaneValue >= 2000 And MethaneValue < 15000 Then
        MethanePriority = 2

    ElseIf MethaneValue >= 15000 Then
        MethanePriority = 4
End If


If EthaneVaule < 1000 Then
    EthanePriority = 1

    ElseIf EthaneVaule >= 1000 And EthaneVaule < 2250 Then
        EthanePriority = 3

    ElseIf EthaneVaule <= 2250 Then
        EthanePriority = 4
End If

If EthyleneValue < 1000 Then
    EthylenePriority = 1

    ElseIf EthyleneValue >= 1000 And EthyleneValue < 3000 Then
        EthylenePriority = 3

    ElseIf EthyleneValue >= 2250 Then
        EthylenePriority = 4

    Else
        EthylenePriority = 1
End If

If AcetyleneValue < 1 Then
    AcetylenePriority = 1

    ElseIf AcetyleneValue >= 1 And AcetyleneValue < 20 Then
        AcetylenePriority = 2

    ElseIf AcetyleneValue >= 20 And AcetyleneValue < 100 Then
        AcetylenePriority = 3

    ElseIf AcetyleneValue >= 100 Then
        AcetylenePriority = 4

    Else
        AcetylenePriority = 1

End If

Worksheets("500 kVa").Range("J3").Value = HydrogenPriority
Worksheets("500 kVa").Range("K3").Value = MethanePriority
Worksheets("500 kVa").Range("N3").Value = EthanePriority
Worksheets("500 kVa").Range("O3").Value = EthylenePriority
Worksheets("500 kVa").Range("P3").Value = AcetylenePriority



Action = Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(PriorityRange)

Select Case Action

    Case 1
        Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("AX4").Value = "Normal"
    Case 2
        Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("AX4").Value = "Add in Watch List"
    Case 3
        Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("AX4").Value = "Resample"
    Case 4
        Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("AX4").Value = "Engineering Evaluation"
    Case Else
        Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("AX4").Value = "Error"
End Select

Worksheets(1).Activate
MsgBox ("The Action Has Been Determined")
```

End Sub

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized that I was using "Select" property by accident instead of the "Value" property to get the contents within the cell.

Problem solved